# How to show div when multiple chekboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I need a div with `id="question5_1_block"` to be showed if options 2,3,4 are checked at the first fieldset of checkboxes. One of those or all together, or just 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc. Anything, that is not an option 1.

I am pretty new to this and managed to get them showing and hiding, but if you uncheck one of them the div gets hidden eventhough some checkboxes are still checked and it should stay there unless nothing is chosen or the 1st checkbox is checked.

Thank you in advance for the help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question5_1_block").hide();
})

$(function() {
  $("#Question52").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#question5_1_block").show();
    } else {
      $("#question5_1_block").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#Question53").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#question5_1_block").show();
    } else {
      $("#question5_1_block").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#Question54").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#question5_1_block").show();
    } else {
      $("#question5_1_block").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js></script>
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js></script>
<div class="page">
  <div id="form">
    <h3>Do you have an account?</h3>
    <p class="mb-0">Multiple answers possible </p>
    <fieldset>
      <p class="align-left">
        <input type="Checkbox" id="Question51" name="q5" value="I have it already" />I have it already<br>
        <input type="Checkbox" id="Question52" name="q5" value="No, but I would like to" />No, but I would like to<br>
        <input type="Checkbox" id="Question53" name="q5" value="No, tell me more about it" />No, tell me more about it<br>
        <input type="Checkbox" id="Question54" name="q5" value="No, but inform me when you have a promotion" />No, but inform me when you have a promotion
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="msg5"></div>
    <div id="question5_1_block">
      <h3>How should we contact you</h3>
      <fieldset>
        <p class="align-left">
          <input type="Checkbox" id="Question5_1" name="q5_1" value="By phone" />By phone<br>
          <input type="Checkbox" id="Question5_2" name="q5_1" value="By email" />By email<br>
          <input type="Checkbox" id="Question5_3" name="q5_1" value="By post" />By post
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: just a comment: it´s unlogical for me to be able to check "I have it already" and check "no" at the same time

Comment: Do you mean if 1 of the option 2, option 3 or option 4 checked,   `div` with id="question5_1_block" to be showed?

Comment: Firstly, why is this multiple choice? The answers seem incongruent. Secondly, when dealing with logic like this it's best to base any UI updates based on the value or key of the selected options, not their position within the UI.

Comment: sorry for not explaining this clear enough - one of the option 2, option 3 or option 4 has to be checked so div is showed. One of them or several of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("#Question52").click(showOrHideDiv);

  $("#Question53").click(showOrHideDiv);

  $("#Question54").click(showOrHideDiv);
});

function showOrHideDiv() {
    if (condition()) {
      $("#question5_1_block").show();
    } else {
      $("#question5_1_block").hide();
    }
}

function condition() {
  return $("#Question52").is(":checked") 
    || $("#Question53").is(":checked") 
    || $("#Question54").is(":checked");
}
```

Quick example that should work

Comment: Note that the `showOrHideDiv()` function can be shortened to just `const showOrHideDiv = () => $("#question5_1_block").toggle(condition());`

Comment: Exactly! The code in my answer is not the best, it's just a little refactor that can be improved a lot :)